# How to run Puppeteer from browser console?

Tags: puppeteer

1. I run a puppeteer script
2. It opens browse with the target page

Here is what I'm expecting:

1. The script should not end.
2. I should be able to open developer tool
3. I should be able to type in Puppeteer scripts in the console and watch it automate.

Comment: This is not how it works. Puppeteer is an automation framework. if all you want is to run scripts do it in a normal browser? What I think you'd rather want is to input scripts in your puppeter script instead of in the console.

Comment: Just don't close the browser, or if it's a test you can set a large timeout to keep it open and add a sleep. I'm not sure what you mean by "type in Pupppeteer scripts" though--Puppeteer adds a debug object to the console but you'd have to [expose a custom function](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.exposefunction) that would run arbitrary Node code from the browser. That `exposeFunction` could just be an `eval()` loop I guess (terrible security, but if it's just you, then should be OK). Can you give an example of the sort of thing you want to type in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

The use case isn't entirely clear, but maybe exposing `eval` to the browser is what you're looking for:

```js
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"; // ^22.2.0
import {setTimeout} from "node:timers/promises";

try {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  // WARNING: unsafe to expose to clients!
  // eval() for individual development purposes only!
  await page.exposeFunction("nodeEval", script => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        resolve(eval(script));
      }
      catch (err) {
        reject(err);
      }
    });
  });
  const url = "https://www.example.com";
  await page.goto(url);
  for (;;) await setTimeout(2**30); // sleep forever
}
catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
finally {
  await browser.close();
}
```

[image: running node eval from the browser in puppeteer]

A more involved browser script might serialize/deserialize objects:

```js
nodeEval(`(async () => {
  const x = await page.$$eval("p", els => els.map(el => el.textContent));
  return JSON.stringify(x);
})();`)
  .then(res => console.log(JSON.parse(res)))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Note that navigation seems to upset return values, so that'll have to occur in a separate `nodeEval`.

If this seems dangerous, it is, although keep in mind Puppeteer's `evaluate()` functions are basically `eval()`s in the other direction (safer, since browsers are safer than servers). So don't expose this sort of thing to anyone but yourself in development.

If you want to execute a script from a file, you can use `page.addScriptTag` and pass the script name as a string into your exposed function (although, technically, if you've exposed `nodeEval` as above, you could run `page.addScriptTag` from that).

Another thing to bear in mind: one can manipulate pages pretty reasonably well just using vanilla JS in the console, so the main reason to do this is if you have backend functions you want to run from the console, or need trusted events. Rather than exposing all of the power of `eval()` to the browser, you could create some preset "safe" macros and expose only those. But as long as `eval()` is there in any form (including likely `addScriptTag`, `new Function()`, etc), you would never want to expose this to clients.

The reason this feature doesn't exist is because [there's probably a better way to do whatever you're trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676).